# Model Attribute Fetched as Nil, when value is not nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

If I set a value for a model attribute, it is saved correctly.

I have a model

```
# gem 'rails', '6.1.3'
class Start < ApplicationRecord

end


 s = Start.find(465860)
 s.gear_change = 'test value'
 s.save!
 s.gear_change
 => nil
 s
=> #<Start id: 465860, gear_change: "test value">
```

Why is rails returning nil?

Answer (score 1):

There could be another column called `gear` in your database. And `gear_change` could be the [Active Record dirty method](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActiveModel/Dirty) being called on the `gear` attribute. Since the `gear` attribute has not changed, the `gear_change` dirty method returns `nil`.

One solution would be to access the `gear_change` attribute as a hash value - `s[:gear_change]` or `s['gear_change']`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have overridden the `gear_change` method in your model somewhere which is returning `nil`.

Comment: no.  if i comment out every single line in the model, the same thing happens.  same for decorator

Comment: I had thought it could be a corruption in the database, but the same thing happens on live as local dev

Comment: @Will, I bet there is a column called "gear" in your database. "gear_change" could be the [Active Record dirty method](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActiveModel/Dirty) being called on the gear attribute.

Comment: bingo!  i found s["gear_change"] works yesterday.  and you are right, there is a gear column.  doh!  feel free to add as an answer for some upticks and ill accept it.  Thanks v much!

Comment: Sure, I'll add that as an answer.